# For an input date, find a date cell with same month and year

Tags: excel, vba, date

In my VBA code, I currently am using an input box to get a user-inputted date in the format mm/dd/yy. What I want to do is search a file and find a date format cell whose date matches the month and year of the input. So say for example the user input is 5/20/20, then I want to a cell with any date 5/??/20, where ?? represents any day of the month. Finally I want to record the column of the cell.

So far this is my code. It only searches for/finds the exact input date, which is not what I want.

```
Sub FindMonthandYear ()  
Dim day As Date
Dim inp As String  
    inp = InputBox("enter date", "Date format dd/mmyy", _ Format(Date,"dd/mm/yy"))  
    day = Format(CDate(inp),"mm/dd/yy")
  
Dim col_date_cell As Range  
Dim col_date As Long
Set col_date_cell = Cells.Find(what:=day, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole)  
    If Not col_date_cell Is Nothing Then  
        col_date = col_date_cell.Columns(col_date_cell.Columns.Count).Column  
    Else  
        MsgBox "Date not found in file!"  
        Exit Sub  
    End If  
End Sub
```

Any help would be appreciated!

EDIT: I'd like to restate what I've said in the comments, to hopefully clarify things.
I am applying this code to several files, and each has a single cell that contains a date within the month I am searching for (so one file might have a cell with 5/3/20 while another file will have 5/4/20). In each file there is a row of dates formatted numerically in mm/dd/yy, and this row varies between files. The dates start at different columns between files. The order of the dates also changes between files, such that in one file the most recent date is in the left-most cell, and in another file the most recent date is right-most.

Thank you Tim Williams for your answer!

Comment: Are the dates being searched stored as dates, and are they located in some predictable place on the sheet?

Comment: Are the dates in the file sorted in any way? Ascending, descending?

Comment: Your specs are too broad. Finding a date  - of which we don't know whether it's text or numeric, presorted or random - in a "file" means it could be in any cell of any column on any worksheet. I think you have some information that would make the search easier if provided.

Comment: @Tim Williams sorry but I'm not sure what you mean by "searched stored"? I want to apply this code to different files and the placement of the cell I'm looking for changes between each file.

Comment: @Variatus I want to apply this code to various files. In a single file there are various dates in a row. The row changes depending on the file, and in some files they are arranged with most recent dates in the leftmost filled cell in the row while in other files it is the opposite. Dates in the files are numeric, formatted mm/dd/yy. I will look at the files I have, and see if there is some unifying factor that would make the search easier.

Comment: Can you say it's the first row from the top with a date in its 1st, 2nd,3rd cell? Can you confirm that only that one row needs to be examined? Can you confirm dates are always sorted - never mind the sequence (so that the sequence can be determined by comparing 2 of them)? Can you confirm that there can't be more than one match in a row?

Comment: @Variatus No, your first statement is not true because the columns that the dates are found in change between files. Yes, only one row needs to be looked at, and dates are always sorted and never repeated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub FindMonthandYear()

    Dim inp As String, c As Range, rng As Range, v, my As String
    
    inp = InputBox("enter date", "Date format dd/mm/yyyy", Format(Date, "dd/mm/yyyy"))
    my = Format(CDate(inp), "m-yyyy")
    
    On Error Resume Next 'ignore error if no cells matched
    Set rng = ActiveSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    On Error Resume Next
    
    For Each c In rng.Cells
        v = c.Value
        If IsDate(v) Then
            If Format(v, "m-yyyy") = my Then
                Debug.Print c.Address
            End If
        End If
    Next c
 
End Sub
```

Comment: So far this is working great! Thank you @Tim Williams. There's one thing I don't understand, why does v not have to be declared as a variable (for example, as a string for range)?

Comment: When I'm not sure what type of variable the cell holds I typically use a variant.

Comment: Williams makes sense. Thanks for clarifying.